# Mosquitto: Use non-static callback function

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, mosquitto

I've running Mosquitto on my RPI4. But right know I only can set static callback functions. Is there a way to use class members?

I've tried to use `std::bind` to pass a class member function as callback:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>
#include "mqtt.h"
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    MqttConnector * mqtt = new MqttConnector("piClient", "send", "rc", 1883, "localhost", 60);
    mqtt->startClient();
    return 0;
}
```

**mqtt.h (only important parts**

```
#include <mosquitto.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


class MqttConnector
{
    
public:
    MqttConnector(std::string id, 
                  std::string sendTopic, 
                  std::string receiveTopic, 
                  int port, 
                  std::string host,
                  int keepalive);
    ~MqttConnector();
    void startClient();

private:
    void messageCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, 
                         void *userdata, 
                         const struct mosquitto_message *message);
    
    struct mosquitto *mosqClient = NULL;
    int keepalive;
    int port;
    std::string id;
    std::string host;
    std::string sendTopic;
    std::string receiveTopic;

};
```

**mqtt.cpp**

```
#include "mqtt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

MqttConnector::MqttConnector(std::string id, std::string sendTopic, std::string receiveTopic, int port, std::string host, int keepalive)
{   
    
    mosquitto_lib_init();
    mosqClient = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, NULL);
    
    if(!mosqClient){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory.\n");
    }
    
    this->keepalive = keepalive;
    this->id = id;
    this->host = host;
    this->port = port;
    this->sendTopic = sendTopic;
    this->receiveTopic = receiveTopic;

}

MqttConnector::~MqttConnector()
{
    mosquitto_destroy(mosqClient);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
}

void MqttConnector::messageCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, const struct mosquitto_message *message)
{   
    // I want to access class members like sendTopic / receiveTopic here
}


void MqttConnector::startClient()
{
    // try to bind class members function
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosqClient, std::bind(&MqttConnector::messageCallback, this, _1, _2, _3));

    //other stuff
}
```

This gives me the following error while compiling:

```
cannot convert 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (MqttConnector::*)(mosquitto*, void*, const mosquitto_message*), MqttConnector*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&, const std::_Placeholder<3>&>::type' {aka 'std::_Bind<void (MqttConnector::*(MqttConnector*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>))(mosquitto*, void*, const mosquitto_message*)>'} to 'void (*)(mosquitto*, void*, const mosquitto_message*)'
   83 |  mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosqClient, std::bind(&MqttConnector::messageCallback, this, _1, _2, _3));
```

Why doesn't it work?

Thanks!

Comment: The callback provides `void *userdata;`. This is what I would expect from a callback. You can pass a static function and an object pointer in `userdata`. The callback function may cast the `userdata` to the resp. type and call the objects member function. (This may be done with a capture-less lambda.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem of using C-api from C++. What is the difference between a member function and a free function? When you provide a pointer to a member function a pointer to the class object is implicitly passed as the first parameter. Since C-api doesn't do that, but the problem is well known, the solution was introduced and it is called passing a context. Usually it is done through a void pointer. Functions that register callbacks usually take the pointer to the free function and a pointer to context. Then this pointer will be passed as one of the callback parameters.

In mosquitto case this context pointer is passed beforehand at the creation of a mosquitto object with mosquitto_new.

In order to make the callback function behave like a C function, we declare it static.

Inside the callback function we use static_cast to cast the void pointer to the object that we have provided.

mqtt.h

```
#include <mosquitto.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


class MqttConnector
{
    
public:
    MqttConnector(std::string id, 
                  std::string sendTopic, 
                  std::string receiveTopic, 
                  int port, 
                  std::string host,
                  int keepalive);
    ~MqttConnector();
    void startClient();

private:

    // make this function static
    ---->
    static void messageCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, 
                         void *userdata, 
                         const struct mosquitto_message *message);
    
    struct mosquitto *mosqClient = NULL;
    int keepalive;
    int port;
    std::string id;
    std::string host;
    std::string sendTopic;
    std::string receiveTopic;

};
```

mqtt.cpp

```
#include "mqtt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

MqttConnector::MqttConnector(std::string id, std::string sendTopic, std::string receiveTopic, int port, std::string host, int keepalive)
{   
    
    mosquitto_lib_init();
    // provide apointer to this as user data
    mosqClient = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, this);
                                         ---->
    if(!mosqClient){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory.\n");
    }
    
    this->keepalive = keepalive;
    this->id = id;
    this->host = host;
    this->port = port;
    this->sendTopic = sendTopic;
    this->receiveTopic = receiveTopic;

}

MqttConnector::~MqttConnector()
{
    mosquitto_destroy(mosqClient);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
}

void MqttConnector::messageCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, const struct mosquitto_message *message)
{   
    // Use static cast to get pointer to your class object from userdata
    MqttConnector *connector = static_cast<MqttConnector>(userdata);
    connector->sendTopic;
}    

void MqttConnector::startClient()
{
    // static callback
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosqClient, &MqttConnector::messageCallback);

    // lambda callback
    // beware, you can't use capture here
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(&m, [/*no capture possible*/] (struct mosquitto *, void *userdata, const struct mosquitto_message *) 
{
    MqttConnector *connector = static_cast<MqttConnector>(userdata);
    connector->sendTopic;
});
}
```